# Element in container with overflow:hidden; has width same as parent, despite the overflowed width being wider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Given:

```
<div class=gallery>
     <div class=slider>...</slider>
</div>
```

with gallery having main css as `overflow:hidden; positon:relative;` and as an example `width:1000px;`

The slider then has **"wider"** content, stretching far beyond the width of the gallery which has a set width to 1000px here.

The problem is, calculating the slider width (using `jQuery('.slider').outerWidth()`) gives the same width as `.gallery` element, when overflow:hidden is used.

The only way to get slider to show it's actual width, is to use `position: absolute` on `.slider`

Problem with that is that now, `.gallery` will no longer expand it's height.

I have to somehow manually calculate *(and keep track of)* height to set on gallery. I do not know the height in advance of the contents of .slider.

Frankly, **I don't get why** `.slider` width can not be calculated unless `position:absolute` is used.

There might be a way to iterate child elements of `.slider` and possibly calculate the width of each child, but risks are the overflown children have width set to zero as well.

Anyone know a good workaround for this?

Comment: make it inline-block instead of using position:absolute and you should be good for getting the width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slider.scrollWidth` seems to do the trick and returns the same value as:

```
        var total = 0;
        $slider$.children().each(function(i, e){
            e = jqr(e);

            total += e.outerWidth(true)
        })

        return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set slider width to

```
width:100%
```

with that, it will never go out of its parent width